# Windows Forms Application - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Percebi que não tenho a escolha de um projeto em Windows Form Application no Visual Studio 2017.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei, e vi que existe a possibilidade de selecionar a opção durante a instalação.

**Uma vez que o Visual Studio foi instalado, é possível adicionar a opção de Windows Form Application?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abra o Visual Studio Installer;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vá em modificar;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E selecione desenvolvimento para desktop e clique em modificar e pronto.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Sim. É só executar o instalador novamente e marcar a opção.